# iOS application - Don't support iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I have developed a new iOS application (it supports iOS6 and older versions). It has been tested in iPhone4 and iPhone5, both work perfectly.

When uploading the application to the AppStore, Apple is asking me to provide screenshots for iPad. The problem is that I haven't tested the application in iPad as I don't want it to be used there. Is it possible to specify somewhere that the application is not iPad supported? Will I still have to provide the iPad screenshots when uploading the application?

Thank you,
skull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode you can specify which devices your application will work with before submitting it to the store.

In the project build window you can specify what platform it works on in the device family field.

If set to iphone it will not publish to ipad

[image: 'ere tis]

Comment: Hi @dizzy, thanks for the quick reply.
I had already done that, but, Apple are still asking for iPad screenshots in the submission, is it normal?

Comment: You should be able to proceed without providing the shots. When the app is reviewed they will realise that it is not built for IPad